# JComponent don't know how to create panel without repeat code

Tags: java, swing

I having problem with create panel which will allow me read/write to file. I mean I have some class like book(with fields author, pages, publication date) and another comics class which extends class book. In this class I have 3 another fields and also have this from book. Now I want to create panel to edit object from class comics that panel should have field from both class but I also don't want to duplicate code when I write another class which also extends book.

So far I have

```
 abstract public class book implements Serializable {
    String author;
    String publication_date;
    Integer pages;
public String toString(){
    return "";
}
public void edit(){};
```

}
And this is my class comics which will be edit through jpanel

```
 public class comics extends book implements Serializable {
 Integer number1;
 Integer number2;
 String name;

public Samochod(String author, String publication_date, int pages, 
     int number1, int number2, String name){
    this.author = author;
    this.publication_date = publication_date;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.number1 = number1;
    this.number2 = number2;
    this.name = name;

}

public String toString(){
    return author + publication_date + pages + number1 + number2 + name;
}

private JPanel createPanel(){
    return new editComics(this);
}
public void e(){
     new Frame(createPanel());
}
```

Frame which is container

```
public class Frame extends JFrame implements Serializable {
public Frame(JPanel panel) {
    add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

And I would like to avoid copy/paste code which in every class repeat code which creates fields from book class

```
public class editComics extends JPanel implements Serializable{
comics obiekt ;
private  JTextField author = new JTextField();
private  JTextField publication_date = new JTextField();
private  JTextField pages = new JTextField();
private  JTextField number1 = new JTextField();
private  JTextField number2 = new JTextField();
private  JTextField name = new JTextField();

public editComics(comics obiekt){
    super();
    this.obiekt = obiekt;
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    createPanels();
}

private void createPanels() {
    JPanel upperpanel = new JPanel();
    upperpane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2)); 
    JButton save = new JButton("save");
    save.addActionListener(new ConvertListener());

    author.setText(obiekt.author);
    publication_date.setText(publication_date.marka);
    pages.setText(obiekt.pages.toString());
    number1.setText(obiekt.number1.toString());
    number2.setText(obiekt.number2.toString());
    name.setText(obiekt.name);

    upperpanel.add(author);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("author:"));
    upperpanel.add(publication_date);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("publication_date: "));
    upperpanel.add(pages);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("pages: "));
    upperpanel.add(number1);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("number1: "));
    upperpanel.add(number2);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("number2: "));
    upperpanel.add(name);
    upperpanel.add(new JLabel("name"));

    this.add(upperpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(save, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Can someone give me an advice how can I do it because all time repeat code is so bad but I don't know how do it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a friendly advice you should check your code out unless you haven't compiled.

An error spotted:

```
JPanel upperpane; = new JPanel();
```

It should be:

```
JPanel upperpane = new JPanel();
```

Comment: Sorry for that but made some edits before i add it at so and i didnt check my mistake. Have u any idea how should i solve my problem?